# Setting DataDirectory to location of executable

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, executable, datadirectory

I'm working on an application that uses a SQL Server CE database. For the final final release of my product I'm going to have my database in a specific location, however, for the testing purposes I need to have it in the same location as the program's executable. The problem with this is my DataDirectory is pointed to the directory where it will be located in the final release. Is there a way to find out what the file location of the executable is and set the DataDirectory to that location?

**Update:**

I tried the code below, but now it won't even load the data into the DataGridView.

```
string folder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase);
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", folder);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string folder= System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase);
string dbPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "DbName.sdf");
string connString = "DataSource=" + dbPath;
```

Then you can use the `connString` to open connection to the DB.

Comment: I had a problem with the first line. Please see my updated question above.

Comment: What Connection string do you have then? Is it like `|DataDirectory|\DbName.sdf`

Comment: My DataGridView isn't using a connection string it's using a dataset.

Comment: Can you try instead `string folder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)`

Comment: That gave me the same result. It still won't get any data from the database.

Comment: ok, can you debug and say, what's the folder value and where is your executable actually located?

Comment: That's easy. The executable is in the debug folder. I ran the program just to check and make sure the code was getting the same thing and it does.